Simplifying $(p\vee\neg q)\wedge(q\vee\neg r)\wedge(r\vee\neg p)$
I recently began learning about compound propositions. How to use a sequence of logical equivalences to simplify
$$(p\vee\neg q)\wedge(q\vee\neg r)\wedge(r\vee\neg p)$$
such that it becomes more straightfoward to figure out which combinations of the truth values of $p$, $q$ and $r$ make this statement True.
I don't want to use a truth table, which reveals that this compound proposition is True whenever $p$, $q$ and $r$ have a common truth value.

Why try to simplify it? It is enough to set $p=q=r=\text T$

Simplify it to $pqr+pqp'+pr'r+pr'p'+q'qr+q'qp'+q'r'r+q'r'p'$ (where I write conjunction as multiplication, disjunction as addition, and negation as prime).

Use twice the distibution law of $$ ((a\lor b)\land (c\lor d)=(a\land c))\lor (a\land d)\lor (b\land c)\lor (b\land d)$$

You can develop (like you would develop $(a+b)\times(c+d)\times(e+f)$ ) ; the only thing that you need to know is that $a ^\land (\neg a) =0 $ ; I write $0$, to continue the parallel with addition and multiplication, maybe I should write False instead of $0$)

@ryang I understand now, I was mainly looking for a way to transform the expression into something like (p∧q∧r) ∨ (¬q∧¬r∧¬p), from which it is more straightforward to figure out the truth combinations that make it True

Knowing that for each $a,b,c$
$$(a\lor b)\land c\equiv(a\land c)\lor(b\land c)$$
you may transform the first two terms as
$$\begin{align}
(p\lor\lnot q)\land(q\lor\lnot r) & \equiv ((p\lor\lnot q)\land q)\lor((p\lor\lnot q)\land\lnot r) \\
& \equiv (p\land q)\lor(\lnot q\land q)\lor(p\land\lnot r)\lor(\lnot q\land\lnot r) \\
& \equiv (p\land q)\lor\text{false}\lor(p\land\lnot r)\lor(\lnot q\land\lnot r) \\
& \equiv (p\land q)\lor(p\land\lnot r)\lor(\lnot q\land\lnot r)
\end{align}$$
Now you may substitute that to the original expression to get
$$\begin{align}
& (p\lor\lnot q)\land(q\lor\lnot r)\land(r\lor\lnot p) \\
& \equiv ((p\land q)\lor(p\land\lnot r)\lor(\lnot q\land\lnot r))\land(r\lor\lnot p) \\
{}
& \equiv ((p\land q)\land(r\lor\lnot p))\lor \\
& \qquad ((p\land\lnot r)\land(r\lor\lnot p))\lor \\
& \qquad ((\lnot q\land\lnot r)\land(r\lor\lnot p)) \\
{}
& \equiv (p\land q\land r)\lor(p\land q\land\lnot p)\lor \\
& \qquad (p\land\lnot r\land r)\lor(p\land\lnot r\land\lnot p)\lor \\
& \qquad (\lnot q\land\lnot r\land r)\lor(\lnot q\land\lnot r\land\lnot p)
\end{align}$$
Due to subexpressions $(p\land\lnot p)$ or $(r\land\lnot r)$ all parentheses except the first one and the last one vanish (are false):
$$\begin{align}
& (p\lor\lnot q)\land(q\lor\lnot r)\land(r\lor\lnot p) \\
& \equiv (p\land q\land r)\lor\text{false}\lor\text{false}\lor\text{false}\lor \text{false}\lor(\lnot q\land\lnot r\land\lnot p)
\end{align}$$
As a result:
$$(p\lor\lnot q)\land(q\lor\lnot r)\land(r\lor\lnot p) 
 \equiv(p\land q\land r)\lor(\lnot q\land\lnot r\land\lnot p)$$

I agree with your answer, but I think you missed a term in the last step: there's also $\neg q\wedge\neg r\wedge\neg p$ which doesn't vanish, meaning that the whole expression simplifies to $(p\wedge r\wedge q)\vee(\neg q\wedge\neg r\wedge\neg p)$. In fact, it's easy to check that $p=q=r=F$ satisfies the original condition.

@CarlosSantiToledo Thank you for spotting that, you're right. Fixed.

@MauroALLEGRANZA I have no idea. :-) You might have also added it has same number of binary operators (but less evenly distributed), same number of unary operators and same depth of parenthesising as the original form. However, four upvoting people apparently consider this a useful answer, so possibly it is somehow simpler? Possibly with a smaller number of subexpressions at the first level (two pairs of brackets instead of three)? May be thanks to not mixing negations (i.e., aggregating separately straight terms and negated terms)?

When I look at the propositions as Venn diagrams, it looks like you're saying that you need the inside of a Venn diagram OR the outside of another one, and this for all three Venn diagrams.
The result looks to me like $(p \cap q \cap r) \cup (\neg p \cap \neg q \cap \neg r)$, meaning either the complete intersection either the complete outside:

